# Gaussian integral with Dirac delta function

Tags: integration, calculus

I'm trying to solve this integral and getting confused. Any help would be much appreciated.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \,e^{-A(x-y)^2}\delta(x-y)$$

Update! In responding to a comment asking to provide some context, I realise I've gotten the actual question wrong and it might not be unreasonable that it was coming back as infinite. So, to explain and update the question:

I have a Gaussian noise source $V(x,t)=\int d y\, e^{-A (x-y)^2} \xi(x,t)$, where $\xi$ is a Brownian noise, possessing an average of zero $\langle \langle \xi(x,t)\rangle \rangle=0$, and an autocorrelation function $\langle \langle \xi(x_1,t),\xi(x_2,t_2)\rangle \rangle=\gamma\, \delta(x_1-x_2)\delta(t_1-t_2)$.

I'm trying to work out what the autocorrelation function is for $V$, and so it looks like I should get

\begin{align*}
\langle \langle V(x_1,t_1), V(x_2,t_2)\rangle \rangle &=
\int \int dy_1 \, dy_2\, e^{-A(x_1-y_1)^2}e^{-A(x_2-y_2)^2}\langle \langle \xi(x_1,t),\xi(x_2,t_2)\rangle \rangle\\
&=\int \int dy_1 \, dy_2\, e^{-A(x_1-y_1)^2}e^{-A(x_2-y_2)^2}\gamma \,\delta(y_1-y_2)\delta(t_1-t_2)
\end{align*}

So! This is in fact my problem. Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: It's infinite. Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Isn't it effectively $\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1\, dx$?

Comment: Dan, why not expand your question to give the physical background? We might be able to spot why you've ended up with an infinite definite integral. That would also [bring your question back on topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7140/are-questions-about-mathematics-used-in-physics-always-off-topic).

Comment: If you are confused you could set $u=x-y$ and apply the definition of $\delta$: $\int_{\mathbb R} f(u)\delta(u) = f(0)$ (where $f$ is a locally integrable function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}&\int \int dy_1 \, dy_2\, e^{-A(x_1-y_1)^2}e^{-A(x_2-y_2)^2}\gamma \,\delta(y_1-y_2)\delta(t_1-t_2) \\
=&\gamma \delta(t_1-t_2)\int e^{-A(x_1-y_1)^2}e^{-A(x_2-y_1)^2}\text{d}y_1 \\
=&\gamma \delta(t_1-t_2)e^{-A({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2)}\int e^{2Ay(2(x_1+x_2)-y)}\text{d}y
\end{align}

And if $A>0$, $$\int e^{2Ay(x-y)}\text{d}y=\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2A}}\exp{\dfrac{Ax^2}{2}}$$

so in the end:

$$\langle\langle V(x_1,t_1),V(x_2,t_2)\rangle\rangle=\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2A}}\gamma\delta(t_1-t_2)e^{-A({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2)}e^{A(x_1+x_2)^2/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Gaussian noise source $V(x,t)=\int d y\, e^{-A (x-y)^2} \xi(x,t)$, where $\xi$ is a Brownian noise, possessing an average of zero $\langle \langle \xi(x,t)\rangle \rangle=0$, and an autocorrelation function $\langle \langle \xi(x_1,t),\xi(x_2,t_2)\rangle \rangle=\gamma\, \delta(x_1-x_2)\delta(t_1-t_2)$.

You must be mistaken, still.

1. You can rearrange that integral as $V(x, t) = \xi(x, t)\int dy~e^{-A (x - y)^2};$ it cannot fundamentally be a different sort of noise than $\xi$ is, except that it might have a different mean/variance.
2. Brownian noise does not have a $\delta$ autocorrelation; the (discrete) definition of Brownian noise is (in JavaScript ES6; Python is similar)

   ```
   function* white_noise() {
       var r, a;
       while (true) { // Box-Muller method
           r = Math.sqrt(-2 * Math.log(Math.random()));
           a = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
           yield r * Math.sin(a);
           yield r * Math.cos(a);
       }
   }
   function* brown_noise(r) { 
       var current = 0, p = Math.sqrt(1 - r*r), white = white_noise();
       while (true) {
           current = r * current + p * white.next().value;
           yield current;
       }
   }
   ```

   and as you can see, it explicitly takes an autocorrelation argument and produces a stream of values which depend on prior history.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The disagreement here comes in that I was taking the average autocorrelation function (as implied by the double angle brackets) and you have taken the single value in a given instance, which is indeed a random value. I believe the answer below by anderstood is correct for average values.